# Array_rand() for while loop return no value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an `t1` mysql table.

Below is data:

```
+-------+-------------+
| ID    | type        |
+---------------------+
| 1     | a           |
| 2     | a           |
| 3     | b           |
| 4     | a           |
+---------------------+
```

And I want to `array_rand` by type a, like `array_rand(1,2,4);`

I try my coding as below:

```
$qadfirst = DB::query("SELECT * FROM ".DB::table('t1')." WHERE type = 'a'");
while($radfirst = DB::fetch($qadfirst)){
    $arr = array($radfirst['id']);
    implode(",",$arr);
    $random_keys=array_rand($arr,1);
    echo $arr[$random_keys[0]]."<br>";
};
```

I use the `$random_keys` from w3school, but still not working, How to make the coding works? Thank you.

Comment: _“I use […] from w3school”_ – [faking Adam Savage voice] _Well, there's your problem!_ – http://www.w3fools.com/ – You should really go try and find a better tutorial site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line
 `$arr = array($radfirst['id']);` replace the value of `$arr` every time it
fetch an ID from the database inside the loop, which will result to an array with only one value assigned to it at the end of the loop.

```
$arr array(1) 
  integer 4
```

Do something like this

```
<?php
  $i = 0;
  while($radfirst = DB::fetch($qadfirst)){
    $arr[$i++] = $radfirst['id'];
  }
  $random_keys = array_rand($arr, 1);
  echo $arr[$random_keys]."<br>";
?>
```

as you loop through ID fetch from the database, get the ID and assign it to `$arr` the type array and increment the index value with `$i` or whatever variable you chose.

Outside the loop, use `array_rand($arr, 1)` to get the random keys and assign to `$random_keys` and the value of `random_keys` use it as an index value for `$arr`. `$arr[$random_keys]`.

Comment: Your Welcome.I'm glad to know to that